# Remove time codes from transcript. I'm using Word for Mac version 16.78.3 macOS Ventura 13.5.2

Tags: mac, microsoft-word

I've copy/pasted a Youtube transcript into Word for Mac version 16.78.3. and removed all paragraph breaks.
Now I'd like to remove all the time codes so the text that looks like this:

0:00 millions of people opt to retire and 0:02 live abroad each year either for a 0:04 better lifestyle climate a change of 0:05 scenery or just for the sake

becomes:

millions of people opt to retire and live abroad each year either for a better lifestyle climate a change of scenery or just for the sake

Please note that time codes increase to 10:00 and beyond.
Is there a way to accomplish this using find and replace? Wildcards maybe?

Comment: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)